# Program correctness in Discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, programming

Given a nonzero integer a and $b∈\Bbb N$, we want to compute $a^b$.  Consider the following recursive algorithm  $\operatorname{POW}(a,b)$.

> If $b=0$, return $1$
>
> Otherwise, if b is odd, return $a\cdot(\operatorname{POW}(a,\lfloor b/2\rfloor))^2$.
>
> Otherwise (i.e., if $b>0$ and $b$ is even), return $(\operatorname{POW}(a,\lfloor b/2\rfloor))^2$.

And we want to prove that POW is correct. Namely, to prove that POW halts and returns $a^b$.

For the proof:
Let $p(b)$ be the predicate $\operatorname{POW}(a,b)$ halts and returns $a^b$.
It is easy to prove the base case which is: when $b=0$, we observe that $\operatorname{POW}(a,0)$ halts and returns $1$, which is equal to $a^0$.
But I am not sure how to continue the inductive step.

Can somebody give me some hints?

Comment: please add your program as text. Put four blanks at the start of each lien to format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Given a nonzero integer $a\in \Bbb N$ and $b∈\Bbb N_0$, we want to compute $a^b$.  Consider the following recursive algorithm  $\operatorname{POW}(a,b)$.

```
function POW(a,b):
    If b=0:
        return 1
    else if b is odd:
        return a*POW(a,[b/2])^2
    else (b is even):
        return POW(a,[b/2])^2
```

Proof by induction:

$\text{POW}(a,0)=1=a^0$, so $\text{POW}(a,b)=a^b$, if $b=0$

Assume we have already proved this for $b-1$. If $b$ is odd, then  $b=2n+1$. Then we return $$\text{POW}(a)=a\cdot\text{POW}(a,[b/2])^2=a\cdot\text{POW}(a,n)^2=a\cdot (a^n)^2=a^{2n+1}=a^b$$
The equation $\text{POW}(a,n)=a^n$ holds because $n\le b-1$.
If b is even, then $b=2n$. Then we return $$\text{POW}(a)=a\cdot\text{POW}(a,[b/2])^2=\text{POW}(a,n)^2=(a^n)^2=a^{2n}=a^b$$
Again the equation $\text{POW}(a,n)=a^n$ holds because $n\le b-1$.

---

A *non recursive version of the algorithm* is the following:

```
function POW(a,b):
    r:=1
    m:=a
    e:=b
    # r*m^e = a^b
    while e>=0:
        if e=0:
            # r*m^e = a^b
            return r
        else if e is odd:
            r:=r*m
            e:=e-1
            # r*m^e = a^b
        else if m is even:
            m:=m^2
            e:=e/2
            # r*m^e = a^b
```

`#` is a comment sign here. `r*m^e` is the **loop invariant**. It remains `a^b` after each step (check it!). So if `e=0` and the function returns `r`, `r` is `a^b`.